# WooCommerce Купоны

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Вопрос по купонам. Я вывожу список купонов в Личном кабинете покупателя. На каждого покупателя стоит ограничение ввиде только одного раза использования купона, т.е. раз использовал и всё, купон для даного пользователя не действителен.

Как я могу сделать проверку на эту логику и вывести к примеру "Купон использован" на страницу в Личном кабинете?

Вот мой код:

```
$couponargs = array(
   'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
   'post__in' => $couponarrayfinal,
   'orderby' => 'title',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1');

$coupons = get_posts($couponargs);

<div class="wt-mycoupons">
   <div class="mycoupons-title">Мои купоны</div>
   <ul>
       <?php
       foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {

           $coupon_time = new WC_Coupon( $coupon->ID );
           $expires = $coupon_time->get_date_expires();

           echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon'>";
           echo "<div class='coupon-info'>";
           echo "<div class='title-coupon'>";
           echo "$coupon->post_title";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<div class='desc-coupon'>";
           echo "$coupon->post_excerpt";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "</div>";
           echo "<div class='coupon-expiry__time'>";
           if ( $expires ) {
              $date_end = $expires->format('d.m.Y');
              $date = strtotime("$date_end");
              $remaining = $date - time();
              $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
           echo "Купон действует еще ";
           echo $days_remaining;
           echo " дн.";
           }
           echo "</div>";
           echo "</li>";
       }
       ?>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так может выглядеть полный код:

```
$coupon_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'shop_coupon',
    'post__in'       => $coupon_array_final,
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);

$coupon_posts = get_posts( $coupon_args );
?>

    <div class="wt-mycoupons">
        <div class="mycoupons-title">Мои купоны</div>
        <ul>
            <?php
            foreach ( $coupon_posts as $coupon_post ) {
                $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_post->ID );

                $expires = $coupon->get_date_expires();
                if ( $expires ) {
                    $date_end       = $expires->format( 'd.m.Y' );
                    $date           = strtotime( "$date_end" );
                    $remaining      = $date - time();
                    $days_remaining = 'Купон действует еще ' . floor( $remaining / 86400 ) . ' дн.';
                } else {
                    $days_remaining = '';
                }

                $used = false;
                if ( $coupon->get_usage_limit() > 0 && $coupon->get_usage_count() >= $coupon->get_usage_limit() ) {
                    $used = true;
                }
                $used_by      = array_count_values( $coupon->get_used_by() );
                $used_by_user = isset( $used_by[ $user_id ] ) ? $used_by[ $user_id ] : 0;
                if ( $coupon->get_usage_limit_per_user() > 0 && $used_by_user >= $coupon->get_usage_limit_per_user() ) {
                    $used = true;
                }

                if ( $used ) {
                    $used_text = 'Купон использован';
                } else {
                    $used_text = '';
                }

                ?>
                <li class="wt-single-coupon">
                    <div class="coupon-info">
                        <div class="title-coupon">
                            <?php esc_html( $coupon->get_code() ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="desc-coupon">
                            <?php esc_html( $coupon->get_description() ); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="coupon-expiry__time">
                        <?php esc_html( $days_remaining ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="coupon-used">
                        <?php esc_html( $used_text ); ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Я заменил очень неудачное наименование переменной `$coupon_time` на `$coupon`, потому что в этой переменной - объект купона, где поля времени - лишь часть.

Кроме того, привёл код к стандартам кодирования WordPress.